# Replace the slug of parent pages with #

Tags: menus, dropdown, mobile, customization

I'm creating a Wordpress site with a Superfish CSS3 / Jquery dropdown menu, complete with hoverIntent as displayed here:

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples

As far as I can see, this menu works well on mobile devices, because the link values refer to the same page, like `#a`, so that clicking a link does not cause the page to reload.

Please bear with me. I know that the right way would be to replace the dropdown menu entirely (with a select box or some other tool), but I need to have the exact same experience as on a desktop (long story).

My question is: how can I replace the href value of parent pages, with an internal link  like `#a`?

My guess would be that doing this via jQuery would be the best solution. What are your views on this and could someone please provide a practical answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **off topic** - should be moved to SO.

Comment: I understand this could be seen as a non-Wordpress question, but your answer proves my questions' validity here, no? :-)

Comment: No, it doesn't :) I've just proven, that your problem with Suckerfishe is a plain js problem. I also showed you, that you have alternatives, that avoid having this problem (as well as having Suckerfish). As I'm one of the higher rep users here, I just try to show others how cosy our place is and that you can help each other in a friendly way :)

Comment: Alright, kaiser, you have a point! I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for your friendly suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Superfish actually does not rely on in-page links in order to show the submenus on touch devices (although admittedly I'm basing this solely on iOS devices).

Simply tap once on a top-level menu item and its submenu should show. A subsequent tap on the same top-level menu item would cause the browser to load that link.

Comment: Thanks, joel. I'll be testing it out on Android devices to confirm this!

Answer (score 1):

You could do multiple things to get this working:

```
jQuery( '.your-nav-menu-item-class' ).on( 'click', function( e )
{
    event.preventDefault();

    // replace the link here

    return false;
}
```

You could also just use [a walker class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=nav_menu+walker).

Or one of the filters inside [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_nav_menu/) - just [check the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.2/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L137).

- Before the Walker: `apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', $sorted_menu_items, $args )`
- After the Walker: `apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_items', $items, $args )`
- Same, but more specific: `apply_filters( "wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items", $items, $args )`
- The resulting HTML: `apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu', $nav_menu, $args )`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gives a clear view of the functions of the wp_nav_menu. Thank you for providing an alternative aswell. Very useful!